# Importing certificate to certificate store with power shell script doesn't work but manually works

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I am creating SSL certificate to bind to my website. I am using power shell script to automate my process from creation to importing the certificate to Certificate store. Once I bind the certificate to my website, my website does not work. but if I manually import the certificates to the certificate store and bind it to my website. I do no face any issues.

I am calling a script which adds root certificate to Trusted Root and client certificate to Personal store.

```
$pfx = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 
$rootCertImportPath = $runtimeDirPath + $rootCertName
$pfx.import($rootCertImportPath,$rootCAPass,"Exportable,PersistKeySet") 

$store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::Root,
    "localmachine"
)
$store.open("MaxAllowed") 
$store.add($pfx) 
$store.close()
```

I am trying to import .cer file extension using $pfx.import call.
Do i need to pass additional arguments to the below mentioned function ?

```
$pfx.import($rootCertImportPath,$rootCAPass,"Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't importing the PFX, you are importing only public certificate without private key. So the correct call is:

```
$pfx.import($rootCertImportPath)
```

no other arguments are used.